# Finite speed of propagation for a PDE

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $u(s,t,x)$ solve the equation
$$ i \partial_s u +\partial^2_t u - \partial^2_x u =0$$
on the set $[0,1]^3$ and suppose that 
$u(0,t,x)=0$ on $[0,1]^2$ and that
$$ u(s,0,x)=\partial_t u(s,0,x)=0$$
for all $x,s \in [0,1]$

My question is whether it follows that the function $u$ must also vanish in the typical domain of dependence 
$$\{(s,t,x)| s \in (0,1)\quad t \in (0,\frac{1}{2}) \quad x \in (t,1-t)  \} $$

My intuition tells me that since the principal symbol is hyperbolic, this property must hold but I’m not sure and since I could not prove it.

Comment: The principal part of your operator is **not** hyperbolic. Using $\sigma, \tau, \xi$ for the dual variables, the principal symbol is $P_2(\sigma,\tau,\xi) = - \tau^2 + \xi^2$. This is not hyperbolic in the $\tau$ direction as for any $\sigma \neq 0$, the mapping $\tau \mapsto P_2(\sigma,\tau,0)$ has a double root.

Comment: Yes you are correct, and that is why heuristically I only expect the finite speed of propagation to hold in the region that I defined. It could still easily be wrong